# Asking a question

Tags: support, asking-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How to ask questions the smart way](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1472/how-to-ask-questions-the-smart-way)

How do I ask a good question?

I am asking this because sometimes when I ask a question, I get downvotes. Even if it is a simple issue.

Comment: jjj, apart from [that FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1472/how-to-ask-questions-the-smart-way), please note the difference between [your original question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/89522/revisions) and @John's edits. A title that actually summarizes your question would even make things better. Success!

Comment: Although this is a dupe, I +1 you for giving a crap.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't ask a question that you can Google and find an answer easily.
- Make sure your question is not a duplicate
- Give enough context (read your  question to make sure it's "understandable" by others, don't just click submit)
- Add code samples, if applicable.
- Re-read your question before submitting it for both grammatical and spelling mistakes as
  not all the audience are good English speakers (error might lead to wrong understanding pretty easily)
- Use tags that describe your question, but don't over use them

Answer (score 3):

I always post this link when questions are poorly worded:

[Writing the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx)

I think the main thing here is to have a clear problem statement and supporting code/examples to back it up. People have to understand you if they are to help you.